# Yup and useForm validation errors does not trigger when contact is form is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, yup

I am using react-hooks and yup for my contact form. I have added my yup schema as expected and error boundaries but they don't trigger when I try to submit it with empty fields. The empty form goes straight to the database which I don't want. Why is it not triggering?

My contact form code is as follows:

````
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";
 
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  fullName: yup.string().required("Please enter your full name"),
  email: yup.string().required("Please enter your email"),
  select: yup
    .string()
    .oneOf(["webSolutions", "mobileSolutions", "devOps", "research", "uiux"])
    .required("Please choose one of our services"),
  message: yup.string().required("Message can not be left blank"),
});

const Contact = () => {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [selecttype , setSelectType ] = useState([]);

 
  const {
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection("contacts")
      .add({
        fullName: fullName,
        email: email,
        selecttype : selecttype ,
        message: message,
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("message has been submitted");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
  setFullName("");
  setEmail("");
  setMessage("");
  setSelectType("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <FormBg>
          <ImageBg>
            <Img src={Image} />
          </ImageBg>
        </FormBg>
        <FormWrap>
          <FormContent>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Icon to="/">
                <img src={dLogo} />
              </Icon>
              <FormH1>Fill in your request details below</FormH1>
              <FormLabel value="fullName">
                Full Name <RequiredTag>*</RequiredTag>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormInput
                type="text"
                name="fullName"
                onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
              />
              <ErrorTag>
                <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="fullName" />
              </ErrorTag>

              <FormLabel value="email">
                Email <RequiredTag>*</RequiredTag>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormInput
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="example@email.com"
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
              <ErrorTag>
                <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="email" />
              </ErrorTag>
              <FormLabel value="services">
                What would you wants to do for you?
                <RequiredTag>*</RequiredTag>
              </FormLabel>
              <select
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const selectedOption = e.target.value;
                  setSelectType (selectedOption);
                  console.log(selectedOption);
                }}
              >
                <option>Select ...</option>
                <option value="webSolutions">Web Solutions</option>
                <option value="mobileSolutions">Mobile Solutions</option>
                <option value="devOps">DevOps Solutions</option>
                <option value="research">Research Assistance</option>
                <option value="uiux">UI/UX Design</option>
              </select>
            
              <ErrorTag>
                <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="select" />
              </ErrorTag>
              <FormLabel value="message">
                Message <RequiredTag>*</RequiredTag>
              </FormLabel>
              <textarea
                name="message"
                placeholder="Tell us more about your request like bugdets, questions and more"
                onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              />
              <ErrorTag>
                <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="message" />
              </ErrorTag>
              <FormButton type="submit">Submit Request</FormButton>
              <Text>We respond within 48 hours</Text>
            </Form>
          </FormContent>
        </FormWrap>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Contact;```
````

Comment: You are not using it correctly, take a look to the nice and clean example from the documentation. https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#CustomHookwithResolver

Answer (score 2):

You can also set `.required()` on your `yup.object().shape({...})` which will make sure that the object will not be empty when validating.

It will look like this:

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  // Your shape fields
}).required(); // -> here is where you add it
```

**Edit**

You are also not using React Hook Form's submit wrapper, this is probably why the form gets submit even though there are errors.

```js
const { handleSubmit } = useForm();

const yourSubmitHandler = () => {
  // ...
};

return (
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(yourSubmitHandler)}>
    {/* Rest of the form  */}
  </Form>
);
```

Comment: Where should I add it because it is still submitting an empty form.

Comment: @Soloh I edited the answer to show where you have to add it.

Comment: that didn't help but I found the solution. Check my answer. Thanks for the support anyways. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Since I was using react-hooks useForm and yup to validate my form, I had to use the data captured in the form by passing it to the onSubmit function to my firebase db like this:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    db.collection("contacts")
      .add({
        fullName: data.fullName,
        email: data.email,
        select: data.select,
        select2: data.select2,
        message: data.message,
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("message has been submitted");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
  };
```

This works perfectly and I hope it does for anyone else who might be using react-hook useForm and yup for validation.

Comment: Glad you found a solution but this doesn't answer the fact that your validation is not stopping your submit from triggering. I think I found the solution and I edited my answer, you forgot to use React Hook Form's submit wrapper.